# Trying to get a total value from a Jtable by adding the last value entered plus the total

Tags: java, jtable

I'm trying to get a total value from a table but every time I enter a new value on the table the system is adding all the number on the column plus the total. However I want it to add the last value entered plus the total. Help please.

```
for (y = 0; y < 7; y++) {
    if (table.getValueAt(y, 0) == null) {
        break;
    }
}
table.setValueAt(nameLbl.getText(), y, 0);
table.setValueAt(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()), y, 1);
Double price = Double.parseDouble(priceLbl.getText()
                    .replaceAll("£", "")) * Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
            table.setValueAt(String.format("%.2f", price), y, 2);


for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    if (table.getValueAt(i, 1) == null) {
        break;
    } else {
        itemlabel +=  Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(table.getValueAt(
                            i, 1)));

        costlabel += Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(table
                            .getValueAt(i, 2)));

        itemLbl.setText(String.valueOf(itemlabel));
        ttlCostLbl.setText(String.format("£%.2f", costlabel));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the working code?

Comment: I'm wondering if I understnad your question correctly, but why do use 7 in in the for-statment and not getRowCount() if you want the total.

Comment: Some related [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjtable%5d%20sum) for reference.

Comment: Hi @beniton , you can find all the files i used on the following link: BackEnd.java  -->  [link](https://gist.github.com/sele-02/c35d072882e6ba3187dfe0b6b4db1581)                                                       GUI.java  ---->  [link](https://gist.github.com/sele-02/f1e8b0f4c1da653618faa56746b4f883)

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that focuses on the problem you describe.